Standard Deviation Calculation in Detectron2 Evaluation Only Works When Resuming Training
I'm using Detectron2 to train a model on my custom dataset. I've implemented a custom evaluation class, COCOEvaluatorWithStdDev, to calculate standard deviation along with other metrics. However, I've noticed that the standard deviation only shows valid results (i.e., non-NaN values) when I resume training from a checkpoint. When starting training from scratch, the standard deviation appears as NaN.
Here are some key snippets:
class COCOEvaluatorWithStdDev(COCOEvaluator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.aps = []
        self.metrics = {}

    def evaluate(self):
        results = super().evaluate()
        self.aps.append(results['bbox']['AP'])
        self.metrics = {
            'bbox': {
                'AP': np.mean(self.aps),
                'AP_std': np.std(self.aps)
            }
        }
        return self.metrics

Training and Evaluation
cfg = get_cfg()
# ... [Configuration settings]

trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=True)  # or resume=False

if cfg.TEST.EVAL_PERIOD > 0:
    evaluator = COCOEvaluatorWithStdDev(cfg.DATASETS.TEST[0], cfg, True, output_dir=cfg.OUTPUT_DIR)
    val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, cfg.DATASETS.TEST[0])
    print(inference_on_dataset(trainer.model, val_loader, evaluator))


When training from scratch (resume=False), the AP_std value in the results shows as NaN.
When resuming training (resume=True), AP_std is calculated correctly.
I remember reading the cause on a Forum, but I cannot find it again, it had something to do with Detectron2 or COCOEvaluator appending calculated results only when having previous data.
Other possible causes I thought of:

The evaluator might not be accumulating results correctly when starting from scratch.
There could be an issue with the data collection or calculation process that only manifests when the training isn't resumed.

How can I ensure the standard deviation is calculated correctly in both scenarios?
